Could Matthew 7:24-26 have been alluding to a shared historic cultural experience of "aggregates-based construction work" in Egypt?
Matthew 7:24-26 has the Parable of the Wise and the Foolish Builders.
The meaning of the parable is famous (and not part of this question) but could it also have borne any historic reference to the captivity in Egypt, as contrasting with the construction of God's house atop the Temple Mount?
The right areas of Egypt were sandy in ancient times (which isn't a given!):-
Herodotus 2.8 - - On the side of Libya, Egypt is bounded by another range of rocky mountains among which are the pyramids; these are all covered with sand, and run in the same direction as those Arabian hills that run southward.
And although I think historians have since worked out the pyramids weren't built by Jewish slaves, that came from Josephus, so it's possible the idea had currency in Jesus' time:-
Josephus, Antiquities of the Jews - 2.24 - - And having, in length of time, forgotten the benefits they had received from Joseph, particularly the crown being now come into another family, they became very abusive to the Israelites, and contrived many ways of afflicting them; for they enjoined them to cut a great number of channels for the river, and to build walls for their cities and ramparts, that they might restrain the river, and hinder its waters from stagnating, upon its running over its own banks: they set them also to build pyramids
If then the 'rock' of the faith rests on the Exodus, which is the experience of being redeemed from captivity, perhaps the house on the sand is the rock, and the parable requires the faithful not only to have accepted the teachings but to have tested them and found them true. That seems nice, but it's whether the allusion is there in the words?

UPDATE 23/08/24 7pm
It's been contended that it's far-fetched for the parable to refer to the book of Exodus.
I submit that if someone was literate and wealthy enough to invest in  Matthew's gospel, they probably had two houses. And their country estate that's prone to flooding they wouldn't have built themselves, or (perish the thought) lived there during the rainy season. The captivity in Egypt is more real and vivid for the elite than real-life construction activity, so it's virtuous to offer an explanation of the parable that's purely literary and doesn't require anything to be fetched from real life.
UPDATE 25/08/24 4pm
οἰκία is a key term in Exodus 8-13, appearing 35 times in reference to the houses of the Egyptians being struck by the plagues (x15) and the houses of the Jews undergoing the Passover (x20). The house of the Pharaoh is struck by flies at 8:24 and the Pharaoh's son is killed in the house of the Pharaoh at 12:30 (Κύριος ἐπάταξεν πᾶν πρωτότοκον). At Exodus 14:28 Pharaoh's army are washed away (τὸ ὕδωρ ἐκάλυψεν τὰ ἅρματα); in Matthew 7:27 (οἱ ποταμοὶ καὶ ἔπνευσαν οἱ ἄνεμοι προσέκοψαν τῇ οἰκίᾳ). With the 3 verses emphasized by similar sound-devices.

Everyone knows that stable foundation = good, unstable foundation = bad. You want to build a house, first thing they do is a geological survey to figure out how deep the foundation needs to go. This is the A in the ABCs of building, why do you think it needs to be a reference to an ancient historical event to make sense?

@user111403 why does it need to refer to anything else? μου τοὺς λόγους τούτους isn't the teachings it's the advice not to build on sand. Jesus was giving a construction tip based on his father's business, and those who didn't follow it, well - their houses fell down. Maximum simples, no fish scared, and the pope's alright coz he's got a big sturdy house. +1

Rejecting far-fetched speculative interpretation is not the same as as excessive literalism, so please don't use that false equivalency. In any case, even absolute literalism doesn't allow this "interpretation". Jesus says like a man who built on a rock, i.e. this is explicitly a simile. The point is, there's an obvious reason why "my words" mean teaching, there's no obvious reason that "building on sand" has to refer to Egypt (especially since we have no reason to think that the buildings they built fell down).

now you're saying the book of Exodus is far from Jesus' audience?

No, that is not what "far-fetched" means

Contextual interpretation:
To me, the idea that Jesus' listeners, many of whom would have been Jewish, might have understood this reference and connected it with their ancestral experience in Egypt is a speculative interpretation.
If anything, it makes more sense for Jesus to have been connecting something more relevant to the audience. Palestine during the time of Jesus provides a more immediate and relevant context for the parable.

Like other countries of that description, it was subject to sudden and
violent rains. The Jordan, the principal stream, was annually swollen
to a great extent, and became rapid and furious in its course. The
streams which ran among the hills, whose channels might have been dry
during some months of the year, became suddenly swollen with the rain,
and would pour down impetuously into the plains below.
Everything in the way of these torrents would be swept off. Even
houses, erected within the reach of these sudden inundations, and
especially if founded on sand or on any unsolid basis, would not stand
before them. The rising, bursting stream would shake it to its
foundation; the rapid torrent would gradually wash away its base; it
would totter and fall. Rocks in that country were common, and it was
easy to secure for their houses a solid foundation. No comparison
could, to a Jew, have been more striking. (Barnes' Notes).

This context would have been more familiar to Jesus’ audience. It could have made the parable more impactful and/or relatable.

Matthew 7:24-27 says:

24 “Therefore whoever hears these sayings of Mine, and
does them, I will liken him to a wise man who built his house on the
rock: 25 and the rain descended, the floods came, and the
winds blew and beat on that house; and it did not fall, for it was
founded on the rock.
26 “But everyone who hears these sayings of Mine, and
does not do them, will be like a foolish man who built his house on
the sand: 27 and the rain descended, the floods came, and
the winds blew and beat on that house; and it fell. And great was its
fall.”


What we see in this illustration is that the teachings of Jesus Christ are represented by the rock. Christ's teachings provide a strong foundation on which we are to base our lives.
Symbolism in the parable:

Rock = Stability
Sand = Instability
The house built on the rock: represents our lives, our beliefs, values, choices, and actions.
The stability of the house: depends on the foundation we choose. The stability of our lives depends on our adherence to Christ’s teachings.
The elements—rain, floods, and winds: represent the challenges and trials of life. Storms can be unpredictable and relentless. The
challenges of life can be too.
The wise builder: represents the Christian who hears the teachings of Jesus and obeys them. Not to only listen to His words
but also put them into practice in our daily lives. Our obedience
ensures that our house is built on a proper foundation.
The foolish builder: represents the Christian who hears Christ’s teachings but does not obey them. This individual may know Christ’s words but fails to put them into action. Such a person builds their life on a shaky foundation, like the sand.

Conclusion:
The core message of the passage: It’s not enough to merely listen to sermons, read the Bible, or attend church services. A firm foundation comes from obeying and living out what we have learned.

But people who farm floodplains are at least as smart as people who buy bible commentaries - there's no archaeological evidence for the Jordan River doing more damage than usual in Jesus' audience's living memory. If that -was- a universal experience, everyone would have raised the objection that "the man who built on the sand knows his house will wash away once a generation on average, but during that time his ability to farm lucrative cereal crops for international export will generate more than enough wealth to replace it - and that's why we all still live round here."

Also, re. "to a Jew." Really Barnes? Are we not able to be moved by memories of our heritage and literature? Must natural events literally wash our houses away for us to be capable of understanding a parable?

Up-voted +1. Much more interesting and edifying than the (yes, speculative) question
